# Detach a recursive method in a separate thread - Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, cocoa

Got a bit of a problem over here... I'm in the middle of writing an ios application (a game), and I need it to be able to pause itself. So I thought the best way to do that is to detach the game execution in a separate thread so that the main thread can simply stop it on demand. The only problem is: when you run the game, a recursive function is called (recursion accomplished by:)

```
[self performSelector: withObject: afterDelay:]
```

and I have no idea how to isolate a recursive method into a new thread. I've tried:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(myThreadMainMethod:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

but it executes without recursion (just the one time)... And I figure, if I detach a new thread again at the end of my method, I'd just get stuck with a bunch of separate threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to stop/start doing work periodically using GCD:

```
typedef void (^loop_work_t)(void);

@interface Loop : NSObject
@property (nonatomic,assign) loop_work_t block;
@property (nonatomic,assign) NSTimeInterval interval;
@property (nonatomic,assign) dispatch_source_t timerSource;
-(id) initWithInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds block:(loop_work_t)block;
-(void) start;
-(void) stop;
@end


#import "Loop.h"

@implementation Loop

@synthesize interval=_interval;
@synthesize block=_block;
@synthesize timerSource=_timerSource;

-(id) initWithInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds block:(loop_work_t)block 
{
    if (self = [super init]){
        self.interval = seconds;
        self.block = block;
        dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
        dispatch_source_t timerSource = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, backgroundQueue);
        dispatch_source_set_timer(timerSource, dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0), seconds*NSEC_PER_SEC, 0*NSEC_PER_SEC);
        dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timerSource, ^{
            block();
        });
        self.timerSource = timerSource;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) start {
    dispatch_resume(self.timerSource);
}

-(void) stop {
    dispatch_suspend(self.timerSource);
}

@end
```

Usage:

```
id __weak weakSelf = self;
Loop *loop = [[Loop alloc]initWithInterval:5 block:^{
    // this will run every 5 seconds
    [weakSelf someMethodOfYourClassDoingUsefulWork];
}];
```

Copy paste this last block anywhere, nest several loops if you need. You can start/stop as long as you keep a reference to the loop:

```
[loop start]; // start the loop
[loop stop]; // stop the loop
```

Comment: Oh, and one more thing: how can I change the recursion interval while the loop is running without stoping it? (For instance, the block of code i'm executing needs to be able to speed itself up.)

Comment: Save a reference to the timerSource and copy paste the dispatch_source_set_timer line to a separate method with a different 'seconds' parameter. Just executing that line will change the interval.